# Correct way to store duration in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a mysql field that has a value of `32:52:00` -- 32 hours, 52 minutes, 00 seconds. However, when I try storing it in django like so:

```
runtime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

How should I store this value, as it seems like django is expecting the time to be less than 24 hours?